# Add Aviation to migration targets for off-topic questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, migration

Would it make sense to add [Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) to the available migration targets for off-topic questions?

Comment: Are there many that should be migrated? I read Aviation.SE quite often and I don't recall seeing any questions migrated from here to there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the [key criteria for default migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196) is the level of migration occurring.

> There's no "right" level for establishing a migration path, but tens or hundreds of migrations with a single digit rejection rate seems safe. Single digit migrations in the last 90 days and/or rejection rates that can order a drink without ID are signs that the path will be a waste of time to establish.

A 10K user can see the [TSE migration stats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats), which show no out-migrations in the last 90 days except to Expats, which is established. A more comprehensive SEDE query for [questions successfully migrated away](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/472000) turns up only five sites with five or more migrated questions since the dawn of TSE:

`Site        Count  Latest Migration
 Expatriates   117  2016-05-04 23:41:43
 Outdoors       22  2015-08-09 22:36:13
 Money           9  2014-06-18 13:34:29
 Aviation        5  2015-07-07 15:30:28
 SuperUser       5  2014-01-08 19:43:14`

Since Aviation has seen only five questions from TSE, and the last was ten months ago, I doubt the powers that be will approve it as a direct migration path. Such things are fraught; many users suggest migrations that are inappropriate for the proposed destination but also *not* inappropriate for the origin.

If you do perceive a lot of questions that would be better-answered at Aviation, then we should step up our efforts to [flag them and have moderators move them](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8109), and then we can make the case for community migration when the stats are more convincing that such a thing would be beneficial to both communities.

Comment: Aviation SE has graduated and is no longer in public beta...

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot Thanks, good to know.

Comment: This seems to indicate in general, we should do more migration (manual) flagging, and less just closing as offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

It makes a few tons of sense to me, but I think this can be added by SE staff only, not by admins. So can the admins please chat with the staff to do so if it's approved?